# protobuf, and tensorflow installation, which version to choose

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I already installed python3.5.2, tensorflow(with python3.5.2).

I want to install protobuf now. However, protobuf supports python3.5.0; 3.5.1; and 3.6.0

I wonder which version should I install.

My question is should I upgrade python3.5.2 to python3.6, or downgrade it to python3.5.1.

I see some people are trying downgrade python3.6 to python3.5

I googled how to change python3.5.2 to python3.5.1, but no valuable information. I guess this is not usual option.

Answer (score 0):

So it is version problem

one google post says change python version to a more general version.

I am not sure how to change python3.5.2 to python3.5.1

I just installed procobuf3.6

I hope it works